# asp:RadioButtonList and jQuery to show hide a panel

Tags: asp.net, jquery, radiobuttonlist

I have an asp:RadioButtonList named rblDependants
which renders as follows and a panel pnlDependants and I need to hide it when radio button selection is "No" and show it when its "Yes". I have tried a few snippets from the forums and none seem to work fine. Can anyone help me pls....!

```
  <table id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl02_rblDependants"  border="0" style="border-width:0px;">
        <tr>
            <td><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl02_rblDependants_0" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl02$rblDependants" value="Yes" /><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl02_rblDependants_0">Yes</label></td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl02_rblDependants_1" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl02$rblDependants" value="No" checked="checked" /><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl02_rblDependants_1">No</label></td>
        </tr>
</table>

<div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl02_pnlDependants">

                    <div class="QuestionWrapper">

                        <div class="Question">
                            <label for="">No. of Dependants</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="Answer">
                            <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl02$txtNoOfDependants" type="text" maxlength="2" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl02_txtNoOfDependants" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="ClearFloat"></div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
​$("table[id$=_rblDependants] :radio").change(function() {
    $(this).closest('table').next().toggle(this.checked && this.value == 'Yes');
})​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​.change()​;​
```

This would work for any number of repeated controls since it finds the `<div id="X_pnlDependants">` relatively.  All we're doing it taking an `<table>` who's ID [ends-with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) `_rblDependants`, taking any [`:radio`](http://api.jquery.com/radio-selector/) buttons inside it and binding to their [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event.  Then either of them is changed it's checking that the result was `value="Yes"` and it was [`.checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Attribute/checked), if that's the case show the panel, otherwise hide it, via [`.toggle(bool)`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

The [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) and [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) are to go up to the `<table>` then to the next element, the `<div>`, since that's what you want to hide/show.  The [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) on the end is to trigger the handler initially, so if "No" is initially checked, it hides the `<div>` on load.

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/Jpsc7/)